# Xcode 7.1 Simulator showing black screen?

Tags: ios-simulator

I'm trying to start my app in the simulator but it's showing me this screen:

[image]

I tried resetting the content and settings, but nothing has worked. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: This seems to be a new thing in Xcode 7 simulators. I just waited and it setup like a normal new iOS device. How long did you wait?

Comment: If you have an iOS device you will know that this is the screen you see when it turns on. It seems fair to assume that it's setting up.

Comment: What the heck... that's weird. yeh I waited but now it's super large / zoomed in

Comment: iPhone 6 simulators have always been huge for me (MacBook 15 inch). There are even scroll bars around it! I really think they should add a scale option for the simulators, instead of displaying the native resolution. They did it for iPhone 4/5 so I don't know why they aren't doing it for iPhone 5/6 :(

Comment: you can scale it by going to Window>Scale and selecting a smaller scale.

Comment: Yea that fixed it @Palle. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

That screenshot indicates that Data Migration is still running.  You can gather more detailed information about the progress by looking at the device's system.log (Debug -> Open System Log).